# Wordpress query optimizing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress one-page website that shows a table of posts (about 30-40).
Each row in a table contains details about a post, and 5 columns of 6 "statuses" (a custom post type) that are linked to the post.
Each status itself shows all "messages" (another custom post type) that are linked to the status.

So in total, I have to make 1 query for the posts, then 40 queries to get the "statuses" for each post, then 6*40 queries to get all messages for each status/

This results in a pretty high load time (about 5 sec), and this is with only one user accessing.

I am trying to find if there is anyway to do this smarter with less queries, assuming that "messages" can change every several minutes so I don't know how much caching is an option.

Comment: If you can take an example with table structure then it will be easy to give any suggestion.

Comment: Zafar beat me to it, but show us what you have now, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: I am using custom post types, with the standard WP tables - wp_posts and wp_postmeta.

I first do get_posts to get all rows in table.
Then I do a foreach loop, and for each row, I do 6 get_posts (for each column), to get the status of the column.
Next for each column I do another get_posts to get all messages attached to status.